# SVG Text transform using CSS

Tags: css, svg

Seems like only on **Chrome** there is no way to transform a `<text>` element using CSS. `transform` works on all other svg elements, except `<text>`.

Here's a [demo page](http://jsfiddle.net/DcjYG/11/) (on hover, both Circle and Text should move with transition)

I do not want to use the `transform` attribute, because I want transition to be applied to the text (in the simplest manner).
Does anyone know if there's a ticket open for this on Blink/Webkit (couldn't find it) and also if there's any way of making it work?

Comment: You could wrap the nodes in a `g` and transform that http://jsfiddle.net/DcjYG/12/

Comment: I totally forgot about that, **thanks!** I feel like you've reminded me my own name. Ridicules!

Comment: Did that workaround even work? Because I tried it here, and it didn't work for me. It seems more like the transform attribute doesn't work in CSS at all.